# Which virtual memory is available to a process ? ( linux mmap )

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, elf

On linux x64 ( 3.16.0-29-generic ), using the code bellow I tried to allocate some specific addresses of memory using mmap. 
I did it both compiling using -m32 and -m64.
So I found that memory addresses ( all addresses are hex - the 3 final zeros are for page allignement ) bellow weren't assignable:
0,000, 1,000, 2,000 up to F,000, sometimes 10,000 ( some times I am able to use it ), and afterwards I arrive to 400,000, and 600,000, 600,001.

As I have understood my code is loaded on 400.000 while something else is loaded at 600.000 and 601.000.
How may I control where the program and data sections are loaded in case I want those addresses to be free, and where is documented which memory addresses should be available.
Why can't I use initial addresses as 0.000 to 10.000 ? ( what is supposed to be there ? ).

The code a little bit dirty is bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

int mprotect(void *addr, size_t len, int prot);

constexpr int64_t cc=0x5858585858585858;

#define Return asm volatile("movq $0x5858585858585858,%rax;");return;
int64_t funcEnd=0x0;
constexpr int maxCode=0x800;
int8_t code[maxCode];
constexpr int pageSz=8192;

char s[0x8];

void testCode(void){
    int a=8,b=7;
    a+=b*a;
    for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(s);i++)s[i]=i;
    //Return;
}

typedef void (*action)(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    action a=&testCode;
    //testCode();

    int8_t *p0=(int8_t*)a,*p=p0,*p1=p0+maxCode;
    while(p!=p1)
        if ( (*(int64_t*)p++)==cc) break;

    if(p!=p1){
            printf("found\n");
            void* myAddr=(void*)(1 * 0x1000);
            void* ma;int cnt=0;
            for(unsigned int i=0x0;i<0x100000;i++){
                void* p=(void*)(i*0x1000);
                ma=mmap(p,0x1000,PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,0,0);
                if(ma!=p)
                    printf("mapping of %p failed\n",p);
            }
            p+=sizeof(int64_t)+2;
            if(ma==myAddr){
                memcpy(ma,(void*)a,p-(int8_t*)a);
                (*(action)ma)();
            }

    }else
      printf("not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to look up the ELF loader to work that one out.

Comment: I looked but didn't found exact loading points, I will look again.

Comment: Why do you think you want to allocate at specific addresses? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I am creating an interpreter, I am looking if I may suppose the environment is fixed e.g. all addresses are available - so I may use code that may be optimized for some conditions.

Comment: Aside from that sentence not parsing properly, it still offers no response to the question. An interpreter for *what*, and why do you think you need fixed addresses? Linux just isn't set up for that; you might be able to make it work with a hack, but I'm still 99% sure you don't really need it.

Comment: From the very little acquaintance with the function mmap, it seems that the OS is able to give up quite all memory, allowing a task to see all the memory space as available. Some space is taken out from the .text and .data sections, according to the instructions in the elf file of the executable, that instruct where exactly to load those sections ( If you use the readelf than that information is there - I am just learning now  ). So I may choose where exactly to load the .text and .data sections, and so believe that the whole "world" is mine !!! (world means "address space")

Comment: About the interpreter, is a programming language. Actually the focus is on pattern matching and dynamic object orientation, but that isn't the question

Comment: About the loading at specific address, I haven't found actually the exact parameters to give to "ld -Ttext-segment=0x10000" to give in order to instruct it !